# Scale watermark in ffmpeg based on video size

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder with videos, all with different resolutions. The goal is to add a watermark on them, which I've successfully been able to done using this batch script:

```
for %%I IN ("C:\path\input\*.flv") DO ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i "watermark.png" -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-5:5" -qscale 1 C:\path\output\%%~nI.avi"
```

The problem is that the size of the watermark changes a lot based on the video resolution. I've understood that I should use one -filter_complex with both scale and overlay, but I don't get it to work. I want something like this:

```
-filter_complex "scale=main_w*0.3:-1 ; overlay=W-w-5:5"
```

To clarify, I want the watermark to be 30% of the width of the video. How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mulvya I've tried it but I don't know how to use it. `for %%I IN ("C:\path\input\*.flv") DO ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -i "watermark.png" -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=iw/4:ih/4[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=W-w-5:5[out]" C:\path\output\%%~nI.avi` gives me an "Filter overlay has an unconnected output" error. It creates the files, but doesn't add encode anything into them.

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you, that works :) I will try to really learn how it works, but for now it does the job. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Mulvya Is it possible to make the height scale automatically to keep the aspect ration of the watermark? Using -1 still scales it wrong.

Comment: If you know the native resolution of the watermark, let's say, WxH, then use `scale2ref=iw/4:ow*H/W` and then add a setsar filter `[wm]setsar=1[wms];[vid][wms]overlay=...`